# Python implementation to find Natural Neighbors of a set of points on a 2D plane

Tags: python, graph-theory, interpolation, scipy

I have been looking for a fast and efficient implementation of finding natural neighbors of a given point (from a set of points in a 2D plane) particularly preferred if written in python. So far, what I have been doing is to use `scipy.spatial.Delaunay` to find the Delaunay triangulation simplices and creating the adjacency matrix from the resulting graph.

Is there any better way to perform this?

---

I have managed to get it done with the scipy package scipy.spatial.Delaunay. My approach was to first obtain a delaunay triangulation of the set of points in the 2 dimensional set of points. And then, generate an adjacency matrix with the generated graph from this triangulation.

This is inefficient, but does the job. Any quicker approaches around?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should have a look at: http://www.pyngl.ucar.edu/Functions/Ngl.natgrid.shtml